# How to get click event on input within mat-form-field?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to clear my selected option when click on the autocomplete button:

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" (click)="clear()" appearance="outline">
    <input matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" 
    [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" 
      [value]="state.name">
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

But click called even when you press a little below.(there is margin within the form)

[Example showing input clear by clicking outside](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k9e7fz?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `(click)="clear()"` on `<input>` tag, 
and not on `mat-form-field` tag.

Add the following to `styles.css` to overwrite css and make `input` tag cover the container full height.

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-infix {
  padding: 0 !important;
  border-top: 0;
}
input.mat-input-element {
  padding: 1.84375em 0 1em 0;
}
```

**[Stackblitz Demo - only clear from input click](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k9e7fz-vjkugh?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.html)**

Comment: I already try it, but then you need to click  exactly on input, that smaller than box...

Comment: @yantrab please check the updated link, now input height is adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way without changing the style, just by add event click to `mat-form-field-flex`

```
document
  .querySelectorAll('p-autocomplete .mat-form-field-flex')[0]
  .addEventListener('click', (ev) => this.clear(ev));
```